# Connecting failure while initiating a call in android device

Tags: android

I have done an android application for initiating a call to another number.

Steps

1. User initiate a call using application. 
   3.Receiver accepts the call and conversation is in progress. 
   4.User tries to initiate a second call

But the connection has gone and a message is displayed .Error message"Error!!Check Your Internet Connection" is displayed now on trying to initate the second call..

GPRS/WIFI is gone when the call is intiated first

Pls Help

But in emulator its working fine... In android device the connection has gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

Checking for the presence of an Internet connection on an Android device

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED) {

            return true;
        } else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {

            return false;
        }
        return false

;
```

Answer (score 1):

GPRS disconnects during a voice call on most of the devices.

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service):

`Class B
    Can be connected to GPRS service and GSM service (voice, SMS), but using only one or the other at a given time. During GSM service (voice call or SMS), GPRS service is suspended, and then resumed automatically after the GSM service (voice call or SMS) has concluded. Most GPRS mobile devices are Class B`

Comment: Im not calling from my contacts..I have done an application. When i initiate a call, its connecting to a server. from there a call is initiated..and all the process are done in the server having an application which can call using net.. I have just made a client of that app